# how to update the MS chart for every 2 minutes using c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to plot a line chart with real time data for every one second in my windows application. For that I need to set minimum (0 seconds) and maximum (10 minutes) values for the chart . After 10 minutes, minimum value is 10 minutes and maximum value is 20 minutes. So I have to display,10 minutes data every time. I need to display previous data with scrollbar from the very beginning.

I tried the following code but I am able to fit first two frames of the chart. That means for example 0-10 minutes and 10-20 minutes.After that I am unable to fit the min and max values(while debugging,getting correct values but chart is not updating with recent min max values).I am not understanding where I did the mistake.I am very new to the MS chart control. Please guide me.

```
int i1=0,i2=120,count=0;
  double min,max;

  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
         chart1.Invoke(addDataDel);
         count++;
  }
  public void AddData()
  {        
        xvalue = getX(count);
        yvalue = getY(count + 1);

        foreach (Series ptSeries in chart1.Series)
        {
            AddNewPoint(timeStamp, ptSeries,xvalue,yvalue);
        }
  }      
 public void AddNewPoint(DateTime timeStamp, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series ptSeries, double xvalue, double yvalue)
    {          
        // Add new data point to its series.
        ptSeries.Points.AddXY(timeStamp.ToOADate(), xvalue);
        ptSeries.Points.AddXY(timeStamp.ToOADate(), yvalue);         

        if ((count% 600)==0)
        {
            double removeBefore = timeStamp.AddSeconds((double)(600) * (-1)).ToOADate();

            if (ptSeries.Points[0].XValue < removeBefore)
            {
                i2 += 120;
                i1 += 120;

                chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.AutoScroll = true;            
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;                   
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 120;

                min = ptSeries.Points[0].XValue;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = ptSeries.Points[0].XValue;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.FromOADate(ptSeries.Points[0].XValue).AddMinutes(2).ToOADate();
                //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum, chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum);
                min = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum;
                max = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum;
            }
        }

        if (count >= 600)
        {
            if ((count >= i1) || (count <= i2))
            {
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = true;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(min, max);
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = max;
            }
        }

        chart1.Update();        
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();           
    }
```

Comment: Question: have you tried moving your `if (count >= 600)` if statement to the end of your method?  I.e. after you've called `chart1.Update()`

Comment: @Berin: I tried your suggestion but not working again the same behaviour.  I am unable to update the chart, for 20-30 minutes.

Comment: The MS chart doesn't do well with updates, and depending on the amount of data it can take a long time to update.  It's been a while, but our team ended up writing our own chart tool to overcome it's shortcomings.

Comment: @Berin: I am unable to display x-axis labels for 10-20 minutes.Could you please guide on this.